# Good hash function.

Tags: algorithm, hash

I can't solve this problem (It is actually an exercise). John  has a good hash function g(x) for integers. But he need to come up with good hash function for strings and the first thing that came to his mind was:

```
def h(s):
if s == '':
    return 0
else:
    return g(g(ord(s[0]) + h(s[1:])))
```

Is this function good? Is this good for last names?

Comment: John needs to stop smoking hash and do his own homework.

Comment: g(g(ord(s[0]) + h(s[1:]))) is (g(g(x)) where x = ord(s[0]) + h(s[1:]). If g() is a good hash function it is approximately random, and g(g(x)) will be no better than g() - in fact it may have more collisions. If g() is a bad hash function having more collisions may be a practical problem.

Comment: I guess he definition of g is also important for this problem

Answer (score 1):

A good hash function will be relatively balanced. By that, I mean the expected data you pump in to it will, as much as possible, equally populate the various buckets.

So it's likely that you integral hash, being a "good" one, will have this property.

If you then think about how many people have the surname Smith (or 王, if you're against cultural bias) and how many have the surname Zemeckis (or 谌), this will *not* be evenly distributed so the Smith/王 bucket is likely to be much larger.

So laying the unevenly balanced surname distribution on top of a well-balanced integral distribution will probably deliver a worse result than you may expect.

To be honest, for surnames, I'd probably just work out the likely data set and distribute based on that. For example (using Latin letters only, to keep it simple), let's say the distribution was something like:

```
Surname first letter     % of data set
--------------------     -------------
         A                    10%
         B                    10%
         C                    10%
         D                    10%
         E                    10%
         F                    10%
        G-Z                   40% total, exactly 2% per letter.
                             ----
                             100%
```

The ideal distribution there would be as follows:

```
Bucket     Letters     % of data set
------     -------     -------------
   0          A             10%
   1          B             10%
   2          C             10%
   3          D             10%
   4          E             10%
   5          F             10%
   6         G-K            10%
   7         L-P            10%
   8         Q-U            10%
   9         V-Z            10%
                           ----
                           100%
```

In that case, the ideal hash function would be along the lines of (pseudo-code rather than Python):

```
def myHash(surname):
    # Use bucket zero for blank and those not starting with letter.

    if surname == '':
        return 0

    firstChar = upperCase(surname[0])
    if firstChar not in 'A'..'Z':
        return 0

    # A..G go to bucket 0..5.

    if firstChar < 'G':
        return ord(firstChar) - ord('A')

    # Then each bucket from 6 onward gets five letters.

    return (ord(firstChar) - ord('G')) / 5 + 6
```